# Multiple lines on multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I am looking for a workaround to  plot smoothed time series for different time series on the same plot. I know I could use `par(mfrow(c(4,1))` to get multiple plots on the same graph. But i want to have the same X-axis for the graph. so that I have something like below.
[image: Plot using cbind]

I have plotted after combining the data sets using cbind. 
Now i want to have the smoothed plots corresponding to each time series in the same graph. By using `par` i get the following result.

[image: using par]

But i do not want the label for the x-axis everywhere. I have used lines in every plot to get the above result.

```
par(mfrow=c(4,1))
plot.ts(ts1,col="green")
lines(SMA(ts1,n=10),col="red")
plot.ts(ts2,col="green")
lines(SMA(ts2,n=10),col="red")
plot.ts(ts3,col="green")
lines(SMA(ts3,n=10),col="red")
plot.ts(ts4,col="green")
lines(SMA(ts4,n=10),col="red")
```

is there any way I could get the desired result using plot or ggplot in R?

Comment: why is the question downvoted??

Comment: In base R, try `plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="")` to remove x axis label or `plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="", xaxt="n")` to remove label and tick mark label.

Comment: i am able to remove the labels and also the indexing of X-axis. But i am not able to get 4 plots together as a single graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ggplot` try this:

```
ts1 <- rnorm(100) # randomly generated values for times series
ts2 <- rnorm(100)
ts3 <- rnorm(100)
ts4 <- rnorm(100)
library(TTR)
df <- data.frame(time=rep(1:100, 8), 
                 id=as.factor(rep(1:8, each=100)), id1=as.factor(rep(1:4, each=200)), 
                 type=as.factor(rep(rep(1:2, each=100),4)), 
                 value=c(ts1, SMA(ts1), ts2, SMA(ts2), ts3, SMA(ts3), ts4, SMA(ts4)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(time, value, col=type, group=id)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id1, ncol=1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('green', 'red'))+
  guides(color=FALSE) + theme_bw() + theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

If you want different y labels for facets, try this:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(ggplot(data.frame(time=rep(1:100, 2), id=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               type=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               ts1=c(ts1, SMA(ts1))), aes(time, ts1, col=type, group=id)) +  
               geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c('green', 'red')) +  guides(color=FALSE) +
               theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) + xlab(''),
             ggplot(data.frame(time=rep(1:100, 2), id=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               type=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               ts2=c(ts2, SMA(ts2))), aes(time, ts2, col=type, group=id)) +  
               geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c('green', 'red')) +  guides(color=FALSE) +
               theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) + xlab(''),
             ggplot(data.frame(time=rep(1:100, 2), id=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               type=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               ts3=c(ts3, SMA(ts3))), aes(time, ts3, col=type, group=id)) +  
               geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c('green', 'red')) +  guides(color=FALSE) +
               theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) + xlab(''),
             ggplot(data.frame(time=rep(1:100, 2), id=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               type=as.factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), 
                               ts4=c(ts4, SMA(ts4))), aes(time, ts4, col=type, group=id)) +  
               geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c('green', 'red')) +  guides(color=FALSE) + theme_bw(), ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I got it..Even though i havent understood it completely, it works. I am not used to using ggplot()

Comment: Just outof curiosity, is it not possible using plot.ts??

Comment: @Vini should be possibly, but ggplot looks much better aesthetically.

Comment: Oh yes.. more to bug.. cant i have labels for y axis as ts1, ts2, ts3 and ts4.. similar to plot.ts?